# html2canvas not working for pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I am working on saving image of div. but div has pseudo element , however i come to know that html2canvas does not support pseudo element.

How to solve it ? Is there any other library to save div as image ?

I am using below link to create a tree structure :
https://codepen.io/P233/pen/Kzbsi
and i want to save this as image.

For this purpose I am using html2canvas

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  html2canvas($("#home1"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = divByteArray;
      document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);

      //window.open(divByteArray);          
      /* $("#test").attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                    $("#test").attr('download', 'checkFile.png');
                    $("#test")[0].click(); */
    }
  });
});
```

Please don't put your comment on function bracket. i am not putting whole function.
I just want to know if there is another library which save div as image?

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css`, `js` at Question?

Comment: html2canvas seems to work just well with your code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMOmpB how did you "*come to know*" that? a simpler example : https://jsfiddle.net/whtsavpp/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html2canvas.js](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1) and [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js) for convert div to canvas and convert to image.

Answer (score 1):

html2canvas seems to work just well with your code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMOmpB

I wonder how you did "*come to know*" that it doesn't work with pseudo-elements?

A simpler example, <sub>which doesn't work in stack-snippet...</sub> :

https://jsfiddle.net/whtsavpp/

```js
html2canvas(d).then(function(c){document.body.appendChild(c)})
```

```css
div:after{content:'hello'}
canvas{border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: @Wei-jye, that is because you are setting the target of html2canvas to your `#d` element, so h2c will make the rendered image's box to this elements bounding box. But your pseudo-element is set out of this `#d` element, hence it is not rendered. If you did select the outer element (here document.body), then you'd [also have the pseudo-element](https://jsfiddle.net/whtsavpp/13/). But I agree that h2c could be smart enough in this case to extend the BBox... Might worth a ticket on the github's project if the latest version still has this behavior.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I notice the behavior and solve it by adding another container with padding to wrap the box, and it works fine now. I already pointed this out in one of the existing github issue tread. Now I'm figuring out how to capture transparent background because by default html2canvas gave me white background

Comment: @Wei-jye for that simply set `:root,body{background:transparent}`in your css. The white background is the default value of one of this nodes. https://jsfiddle.net/whtsavpp/14/

Answer (score 1):

In browsers other than Google chrome, `getComputedStyle()` method on pseudo elements pick the border style from main element. so you will have to include the border style on main element.

Here is the trick, change this code:

```
div::before {
content: 'Hello',
border-top: 1px solid green;
}
```

to:

```
div {
border: 0 solid;
}

div::before {
content: 'Hello',
border-top: 1px solid green;
}
```